# Multi level Dataframe Grouping

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to do a Multi level Grouping with end result in List and Dictionary building. So for example if my Dataframe looks like this blow

```
 X      Y   Z
AAAA BBBB CCCCC
AAAA BBBB DDDDD
AAAA BBBB EEEEE
FFFF GGGG HHHHH
FFFF GGGG IIIII
JJJJ KKKK LLLLL
```

I am trying to merge Y and Z Columns into Dictionary based on grouping from X and Y. hence the end result be like

```
P       Q
AAAA    BBBB:[{CCCCC},{DDDDD},{EEEEE}]
FFFF    GGGG:[{HHHHH},{IIIII}]
JJJJ    KKKK:[{LLLLL}]
```

Is this something that is purely achievable by pandas Functions or do i have to loop and then then process ?

Comment: ah you are right! ..thanks for pointing it out . I have now fixed the question.

Comment: Just curious, I specifically customised solution to meet your required format of list of sets instead of the easier solution of list of strings which doesn't match your layout requirement.  So why you don't choose my solution matching better your required output layout ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in 2 steps:

1. Create list of sets by lambda function within [`SeriesGroupBy.agg()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.aggregate.html) of Series `Z` grouped by `X` and `Y`.
2. Create dictionary with `Y` as key and list of sets created in step 1 as value by using `df.apply()` with `pd.Series()`

Codes:

```
df2 = (df.groupby(['X', 'Y'], as_index=False)['Z']
         .agg(lambda x: [{y} for y in x.values]))
df2 = df2.apply(lambda x: pd.Series({'P': x['X'], 'Q': {x['Y']: x['Z']}}), axis=1)
```

Result:

```
      P                                            Q
0  AAAA  {'BBBB': [{'CCCCC'}, {'DDDDD'}, {'EEEEE'}]}
1  FFFF             {'GGGG': [{'HHHHH'}, {'IIIII'}]}
2  JJJJ                        {'KKKK': [{'LLLLL'}]}
```

Alternatively, if you want to keep all columns in one place, you can also modify the 2nd step to use `result_type='expand'` instead of using `pd.Series()`, as follows:

```
df2 = (df.groupby(['X', 'Y'], as_index=False)['Z']
         .agg(lambda x: [{y} for y in x.values]))
df2[['P', 'Q']] = df2.apply(lambda x: [x['X'], {x['Y']: x['Z']}], result_type='expand', axis=1)
```

Result:

```
      X     Y                            Z     P                                            Q
0  AAAA  BBBB  [{CCCCC}, {DDDDD}, {EEEEE}]  AAAA  {'BBBB': [{'CCCCC'}, {'DDDDD'}, {'EEEEE'}]}
1  FFFF  GGGG           [{HHHHH}, {IIIII}]  FFFF             {'GGGG': [{'HHHHH'}, {'IIIII'}]}
2  JJJJ  KKKK                    [{LLLLL}]  JJJJ                        {'KKKK': [{'LLLLL'}]}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can group by `X` and `Y` column and the aggregate to list. Then create the dictionaries with `.apply`:

```
df = df.groupby(["X", "Y"], as_index=False).agg(list).rename(columns={"X": "P"})
df["Q"] = df[["Y", "Z"]].apply(lambda x: {x["Y"]: x["Z"]}, axis=1)
print(df[["P", "Q"]])
```

Prints:

```
      P                                      Q
0  AAAA  {'BBBB': ['CCCCC', 'DDDDD', 'EEEEE']}
1  FFFF           {'GGGG': ['HHHHH', 'IIIII']}
2  JJJJ                    {'KKKK': ['LLLLL']}
```